# Python - Integrador de banco de dados - Passando variaveis de um select, para um insert digitado pelo usuário

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, sqlite

Bom dia Galera,

Estou começando agora no mundo Python, e gostaria muito de uma ajuda em um programa de integração que estou tentando criar.

**Objetivo da Aplicação**

Pois bem, o objetivo deste programa é possibilitar a integração entre bancos de dados. O projeto esta muito inicio, mas a ideia é poder cadastrar diversas conexões, com variados bancos, para que em uma outra aba, o usuário selecione uma conexão para select e outra para insert, para que possamos passar um select em um banco e devolver os dados absorvidos como insert em outro banco.

Obs: Estou usando PySimpleGUI para criar a interface da aplicação.

[image: Interface da Aplicação]

**Descrição do Problema**

Quando eu passo o insert pela aplicação, o programa retorna com o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, se eu passo este mesmo INSERT chumbado no "cursor_sqllite.execute", o programa funciona perfeitamente.

```js
cursor_sqllite.execute(f"""INSERT INTO ETIQUETA_LOCAIS_COLUNA (
                                    COD_ID,
                                    ARMAZEM,
                                    RUA,
                                    POSICAO,
                                    NIVEL_1,
                                    NIVEL_1_VERIFICADOR,
                                    NIVEL_2,
                                    NIVEL_2_VERIFICADOR,
                                    NIVEL_3,
                                    NIVEL_3_VERIFICADOR,
                                    NIVEL_4,
                                    NIVEL_4_VERIFICADOR,
                                    NIVEL_5,
                                    NIVEL_5_VERIFICADOR,
                                    NIVEL_6,
                                    NIVEL_6_VERIFICADOR)  
                                values (
                                    {(row[0])},  
                                    '{row[1]}',
                                    '{row[2]}',
                                    '{row[3]}',
                                    '{row[4]}',
                                    '{row[5]}',
                                    '{row[6]}',
                                    '{row[7]}',
                                    '{row[8]}',
                                    '{row[9]}',
                                    '{row[10]}',
                                    '{row[11]}',
                                    '{row[12]}',
                                    '{row[13]}',
                                    '{row[14]}',
                                    '{row[15]}')""")
```

Só tenho erro, quando passo este mesmo INSERT dentro da variável "query_2".

```js
while row:
                print(f'{(row)}')
                i = i + 1
                cursor_sqllite.execute(f""" {query_2} """)
                row = cursor.fetchone()
                con.commit()
```

**Código fonte Python que retorna com o erro**

```js
from itertools
import count
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyodbc
import sqlite3
from sqlite3
import Error
from pyodbc
import Cursor

class TelaPython:
  def __init__(self): #Layout
layout = [
  [sg.Text('Cadastro de Serviços'), ],
  [sg.Text('Conexão Select', size = (15, 1)), sg.Combo(['SqlServer', 'Oracle', 'SQLite'], key = 'banco_1')],
  [sg.Text('Query Select', size = (15, 1)), sg.Multiline(size = (100, 10), key = 'query_1')],
  [sg.Text('Conexão Insert', size = (15, 1)), sg.Combo(['SqlServer', 'Oracle', 'SQLite'], key = 'banco_2')],
  [sg.Text('Query Insert', size = (15, 1)), sg.Multiline(size = (100, 10), key = 'query_2')],
  [sg.Button('Processar')]#[sg.Output(size = (150, 10))]
]# Janela
self.janela = sg.Window("Integrador de Dados").layout(layout)# Extrair os dados da tela
def Iniciar(self):
  while True:
  self.button, self.values = self.janela.Read()
banco_1 = self.values['banco_1']
banco_2 = self.values['banco_2']
query_1 = self.values['query_1']
query_2 = self.values[""
  "query_2"
  ""]# conexão sqlite
caminho = "xxxxxxxx"
con = sqlite3.connect(caminho)
cursor_sqllite = con.cursor()
print("Sqlite Conectado")# conexão sqlserver
server = 'xxxxxx'
database = 'xxxxxx'
username = 'xxxxxx'
password = 'xxxxxx'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
print("Conexão bem sucedida com SQLServer")# passando a query no sqlserver
cursor.execute(query_1)# printando os resultados
print('----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
print('Dados do Select')
print(f 'Banco: {banco_1}')
print(f 'Query Select: {query_1}')
print('----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
row = cursor.fetchone()
i = 0
while row:
  print(f '{(row)}')
i = i + 1
cursor_sqllite.execute(f ""
  " {query_2} "
  "")
row = cursor.fetchone()
con.commit()# layout janela de progresso
layout_1 = [
  [sg.Text('Progredindo...')],
  [sg.ProgressBar(100, orientation = 'h', size = (20, 20), key = 'progressbar')],
  [sg.Cancel()]
]# criação da janela `
            window = sg.Window('Progresso', layout_1)
            progress_bar = window['progressbar']
            # loop nos resultados a serem processados
            for i2 in range(i):
                # verificação do evento de cancelamento 
                event, values = window.read(timeout=0.1)
                if event == 'Cancel'  or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
                    break
            # update bar with loop value +1 so that bar eventually reaches the maximum
                progress_bar.UpdateBar(i2 + 1)
            # done with loop... need to destroy the window as it's still open
            window.close() 
            # continuação printando os resultados
            print(f'Total de {i} registros integrados')   
            print('Dados do Insert')
            print(f'Banco: {banco_2}')
            print(f'Query Insert: {query_2}')
            print('----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------')
            text_input = f'Total de {i} registros integrados'    
            sg.popup(text_input)
tela = TelaPython()
tela.Iniciar()
```

**Trecho do Erro**

```js
while row:
                print(f'{(row)}')
                i = i + 1
                cursor_sqllite.execute(f""" {query_2} """)
                row = cursor.fetchone()
                con.commit()
```

**Resumo**

Em resumo, eu preciso passar o insert digitalizado dentro do app. Como sou iniciante, achei bem estranho funcionar com o insert chumbado, e não funcionar digitando o mesmo insert na aplicação.

Caso precisem de mais informações fico à disposição.

Desde já, muito obrigado.